# Display Directory Listing of .htaccess password protected directory

Tags: server, apache2, password, .htaccess

I want to be able to password protect a specific directory but keep others free for anyone to access, but I've found out that when a directory is password protected by a .htaccess and .htpasswd file it disappears from apache's directory listing.

Is there any way to make the password protected directory appear among the other unprotected directories?

Answer (score 1):

Add the line

```
IndexOptions +ShowForbidden
```

to the `.htaccess` file in parent folder of your protected folder.

Comment: That doesn't work, the directory still does not appear

Comment: You need to have `AllowOverride Indexes`  enabled for that directory.

Comment: IndexOptions ShowForbidden works just fine without the plus, why is that?

Comment: See the  "Incremental IndexOptions" section at the end of the [IndexOptions doc](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_autoindex.html#indexoptions) for the difference. Maybe there's a conflicting option somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be what you're after, but you could try limiting the `.htaccess` restrictions to files that are in the directory you wish to protect instead of protecting the directory itself.

Comment: But the problem is the directory is actually a webpage, and I want it so when I click on the directory and when it would normally redirect me to the index.php

Answer (score 0):

Added `IndexOptions ShowForbidden` instead of `IndexOptions +ShowForbidden`